# Iphone library to access iphone photo gallery

Tags: iphone, photo-gallery

Is there any iphone library for accessing the full photo gallery,which should help me to access and upload all the images.

Not looking like three20 application ,expecting some information from iphone api's

Thanks in advance.............

Answer (score 0):

If you're a registered developer, I would suggest visiting developer.apple.com/iphone and signing in there. Otherwise, we can't really discuss it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the AV Foundation Library: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188.

Via ALAssetsGroup and ALAssets, you should be able to access the images located on the device.